# Using meta tables to determine if a query is distinct

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

Does anyone have any idea how to use the meta-table to determine if a query is selecting a distinct value? I can't see to find anything that determines this in Meta-tables related to queries.

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Comment: You can look for `unique` and `primary key` constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT QRYDISTINCT FROM PSQRYSELECT WHERE QRYNAME = :1;
```